# Volume EBS: Month-to-date usage VS Forecasted month-end usage

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I'm trying Amazon AWS EC2 Free Tier. I have a 30GB (Free Tier) EBS (SSD) volume. I am registered at the end of October 2017 at Amazon AWS, in the "Billing" panel I used 3.8 GB of Volume EBS in October and 4.5 GB of EBS Volume in November (**Month-to-date usage**)
The sum is about 9.5 GB. Why in "**Forecasted month-end use**" is it written that I consumed 22.5 GB? Where are 13 GB (22.5 - 9.5)?

How does Amazon calculate the consumption of my EBS Volume? In November I held the instance and volume off. Why does it say I've consumed 4.5 GB?

Comment: Do you have any snapshots?

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you for not ignoring my question. No, I do not have any snapshots.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone can actually answer this, the forecast is made by AWS and I'm not sure they say anything about it. Perhaps you could include a screenshot of anything you're mentioning. Also, exactly what problem is this causing? 22.5GB is within your allowance, so you won't be charged, so no problem?

Comment: "forecasted" means "what the consumption at the end of the month will probably be". You haven't consumed this 13GB yet.

Comment: @tim Ok,  I understand now. It is a prediction of what I could consume. I did not understand this, sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: @Marco Thank you, I didn't understand it before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With such a short usage history, Amazon doesn't have enough data to make a more accurate estimation of your usage.  As time goes on you should see those forecasts become closer to your actual storage use patterns.

Amazon has not made it easy to track your usage and costs.  Different pricing models, so many products and tiers.  I understand that can be confusing.  Perhaps it would help to have some additional information about managing your AWS EBS storage. Here's [one article](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/managing-ebs-volumes-in-aws-cloud) that give more information on what is EBS and ways to use it.

Comment: I have a question: I have an open session 24/24h, I'm trying to build a site but for now I use this instance little. Why does the EBS volume increase by one giga every two days? Nobody visits my page, it's a too high cost!

Comment: Look at your AWS management console under billing.  Check your usage and storage stats to see specifics on what's being added.  And if you are not using this instance, why have an open session?  Its just usage you don't need.

Comment: Now I'm using the instance to create a WordPress site so it is always connected. But my EBS volume grows without practically being used. I don't understand how Amazon calculates my GB on EBS Volume. This is my problem. In AWS Billing there is the "actual usage" but without any other information.